# How to declare functions in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I want just to `declare` functions **without** the implementations. The implementations have to be in another file.

Is this possible and if so, is there some tricky in that?
Is it common practice to do so? I'm curious because I'm coming from a C++.

Example:

----------------- declarations.php -----------

```
<?php
 function first($name, $age);
 function second($country);
?>
```

----------------- implementations.php -----------

```
<?php 
include (declarations.php);

function first($name, $age)
{
 // here is the implementation
}

function second($country)
{
 // here is the other implementation
}
?>
```

Comment: use `required_once` instead, and the way you are doing is correct but may not be optimum..

Comment: You cannot redeclare a function after its already been declared so no his way of doing things above wont work.  As mentioned below though swapping to OO will probably achieve the same result.  There's no php equivilent of a .h :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want is an interface, although it has to be implemented in a class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Since PHP is a scripting language, you still will have to have a direct reference to the implementation with an `include`. There is no linking stage like C++.

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP doesn't have the equivalent of the header files, where you declare a global function and implement it somewhere.

As Daniel wrote, there is something similar, i.e. the interfaces, but their purpose is to describe an interface to which all implementing classes must adhere, rather than indicating a "function placeholder".

Also, PHP, as of version 5.4 doesn't support function or method overload, therefore the same function or method cannot be declared more than once, even with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use object-oriented programming to solve this problem? Abstract class with several abstract methods would do a great job.

```
// File: MyClass.php
abstract class AbstractClass {

    abstract public function first($arg);
    abstract public function second($arg, $arg2);

}

// File: core.php
require_once('MyClass.php');

class MyClass extends AbstractClass {

    public function first($arg) {
        // implementation goes here
    }

    public function second($arg, $arg2) {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need an abstract class, an interface would suffice for headers only.

Answer (score 1):

PHP and C + + are different to this point.
No need to make a declaration and a separate implementation of your function. 
You must do this at the same time (declaration and implementation in the same file), then include (include () or require_once ()) the functions in your script.